# Modifying the result from ActionExecutedContext inside OnActionExecuted in web api asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, custom-action-filter, onactionexecuted

I am writing `custom filter` in my `Web API` and there I want to modify the result of `ActionExecutedContext` inside the `OnActionExecuted` method.

I got the result type as `OkObjectResult` as the `action method` is returning `IActionResult`.

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{        
    var myResult = context.Result; 
    //Type of myResult is OkObjectResult          
}
```

So here how can I convert this `OkObjectResult` to my model `Object`, So that I can use the `properties` and manipulate the values.

Appreciated any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OkObjectResult's "Value" property returns the Object. You can modify the Object's properties or even replace it with a new one. Hope this works for you. If it does, please mark this as answer.

**Sample CODE**:

```c#
public class Student
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

 [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("api/Test/GetString")]
        [SampleActionFilter]
        public ActionResult<Student> GetString(string name)
        {
            if(name.StartsWith("s"))
            {
                return Ok(new Student{ Name = $"This is data {name}" });
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(new Student { Name = $"No Name" });
            }
        }
    }

 public class SampleActionFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public SampleActionFilterAttribute() : 
        base(typeof(SampleActionFilterImpl))
        {
        }

    private class SampleActionFilterImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
        
            // perform some business logic work

        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // perform some business logic work
            var myResult = (OkObjectResult)context.Result;

            //Add type checking here... sample code only
            //Modiy object values
            try
            {
                Student myVal = (Student)myResult.Value;
                myVal.Name = "Johnny";
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to assign OkObjectResult's Value property, it's available only the time of debugging.

Comment: Provided tested sample code. You can adapt to your scenario. (I have implemented an ActionFilter and applied it to a "GetString" method on the controller.) (In the sample code, the "Name" value will always be "Johnny" (as set in the OnActionExecuted method).